# Missing media prompt top box is missing. Have no idea what it's asking for

Tags: premiere, adobe

For some reason the dialogue for the missing media looks like this:

[image]

The top is missing. I don't know what media it's referring to which is a huge problem. How would one fix this? Restarting the program and the computer doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 1):

Is this the only clip that is missing? If so, can you offline the clip, then look into your project to see what's missing. Even if there are multiple clips, you can just offline all, go into the project monitor, you can sort by status in the last column: [image: Last Column]

After you sort, right click on each clip that is offline, then click on link media. [image: Link Media]

Assuming you remember what clip you want when you right click, even if it won't give you the clip, you'll know what you're replacing.